# Вопрос по настройке ethernet подключения на linux-устройстве. В чём может быть проблема?

Tags: linux, arm, embedded

Ответ на команду "ip link" выглядит вот так:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:00:01:92 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Ответ на команду "ifconfig" выглядит вот так:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:00:01:92
          inet addr:192.168.0.136  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe00:192/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3995 errors:0 dropped:961 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:151 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:803060 (784.2 KiB)  TX bytes:14398 (14.0 KiB)
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Устройство подключено к ethernet-кабелю, устройство SK-NUC976, Ethernet 100/10M. Разумеется 100% пакетов теряется, при попытке пинговать что-либо.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Network_configuration

Comment: А что это у вас broadcast IP такой странный - 0.0.0.0?

Comment: Покажите таблицу маршрутизации, `ip route`

Comment: Похоже, адрес интерфейс `eth0` получил через `dhcp`. Что написано в `/var/lib/dhcpd/dhcp.leases` или `/var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-<uuid>-eth0.lease`?

Comment: Ответ на "ip route":
"default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  src 192.168.0.136"

Comment: роуты норм. с какого адреса пытаетесь к нему подключиться?

Comment: "/var/lib/dhcpd: No such file or directory" и "-sh: can't open uuid: no such file"  соответственно

Comment: `cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/*.lease`

Comment: arp работает? `cat /proc/net/arp`

Comment: can't open '/var/lib/NetworkManager/*.lease': No such file or directory

Comment: # cat /proc/net/arp
IP address       HW type     Flags       HW address            Mask     Device
192.168.0.1      0x1             0x2          10:fe:ed:f9:97:8b     *            eth0

Comment: IP address: "192.168.0.1",       
HW type:"0x1",
Flags:"0x2",
HW address:"10:fe:ed:f9:97:8b",
Mask:"*",
Device:"eth0"

Соответственно

Comment: мак видит роутера - значит драйвер пашет.  откуда пытаетесь к нему подключиться?

Comment: `ping 192.168.0.1` работает? `ping 8.8.8.8` ?

Comment: Ввёл команды "ifconfig eth0 <желаемый ip>" и "route add default gw <шлюз подсети>". Появился интернет, стал пинговать 8.8.8.8. После чего добавил пакет "openssh" в конфигурации buildroot. И теперь есть ssh по 22-му порту, и ftp по 21-му порту. Отлично теперь всё

Answer (score 1):

Из того что есть в вопросе:

`UP,LOWER_UP` - интерфейс поднят,  кабель подключен

`UP ... RUNNING` - интерфейс поднят,  кабель подключен

Дальше стоит посмотреть маршруты.

```
ip r
```

И фаервол

```
iptables-save
```

Comment: default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  src 192.168.0.136

Comment: -sh: iptable-save: not found

Comment: `iptables -L` тогда

Comment: Not found. Похоже что утилиты просто нет на устройстве. Попробую поискать

Comment: А может есть nft?

Comment: Накатил iptables на устройство. Ответ на команду "iptables-save" пустой. Ответ на команду "iptables -L": "modprobe: module ip_tables not found in modules.dep
iptables v1.6.0: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded."
nft не стоит

Comment: Всё заработало(и ssh ok, и ftp ok), но настройки сети не сохраняет

Answer (score 0):

Исправил проблему командами "ifconfig eth0 <желаемый ip>" и "route add default gw <шлюз подсети>". После чего стали отправляться пакеты по адресу 8.8.8.8.
Затем накатил пакет "openssh", после чего автоматически поднялось подключение по  ssh(22-й порт) и подключение по ftp(21-й порт).
Плата SK-NUC976.
Конфигурация поддержки драйверов для ethernet такая:

- Nuvoton Devices
- Nuvoton NUC970 Ethernet MAC 0
- OpenCores 10/100 Mbps Ethernet Mac Support

Конфигурация для network supporting самого buildroot(возможно не минимальная, возможно не хватает включения критически важных настроек, ибо работу с сокетами не тестировал всерьёз(кроме ftp и ssh). Можете поправить если ошибаюсь. Список составлен для тех кто испытывает трудности с конфигурированием buildroot для данной платы):

- Packet Socket
- Packet: socket monitoring interface
- Unix domain sockets
- UNIX: socket monitoring interface
- TCP/IP networking
- IP: multicasting
- IP: advanced router
- FIB: TRIE statistics
- IP: policy routing
- IP: equal cost multipath
- IP: verbose route monitpring
- IP: tunneling
- INET: socket monitoring

Есть проблема также, связанная с тем что при перезагрузке настройки сети не сохраняются, когда и эту проблему решу, добавлю это в ответ

Comment: Вы добавили службу настройки сети? какую? я добавлял ifupdown в бизибокс

Comment: Там всё по умолчанию стояло. В базибокс не трогал ничего, на тот момент

Comment: По умолчанию нет ничего. Возможно статический адрес выставлен в параметре ядра и только

Comment: Ну я лично его с помощью двух команд прописываю при старте ос-и.  "ifconfig eth0 <желаемый ip>" и "route add default gw <шлюз подсети>". Соответственно мой ip известен был, как и шлюз. Поэтому заработало. Правда сегодня снова все отвалилось, непонятно почему

Comment: Маску не забывай)) частая ошибка

Comment: А для решения перезагрузки поставь уже наконец ifupdown или простой аналог

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо. Кстати, а возможно ли как-то сохранить несколько разных ip-шников, чтобы утилиты ОС пробовали разные вариации ip-шников, при старте и использовали только одну рабочую?

Comment: Несколько адресов возможно, несколько шлюзов тоже легко. Но чтоб само выбирало один рабочий - нужно или костылить или ставить какой-нибудь bird

Comment: Хорошо. А вот как первый пункт можно было бы решить? С костылями уж сам справлюсь скорее всего